# Set the scroll position in WinJS.UI.ListView

Tags: javascript, listview, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winjs

I want to scroll my ListView on a specific item automatically. The ListView must auto-scroll to an item from his index.

```
listView.ensureVisible(itemIndex);
```

But it's not working. Another alternative:

```
yourListView.currentItem = { index: 8, hasFocus: true, showFocus: true }
```

And it's failed also.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you have to wrap your call to `ensureVisible(index)` in a call to msSetImmediate. Not sure exactly why this is the case, probably a bug, but works for me. Example:

```
msSetImmediate(function (){ listView.ensureVisible(4);} );
```

If you look at the documentation for [setImmediate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453394.aspx) (msSetImmediate being a Microsoft specific implentation), the function is described as:

> Requests that a function be called when current or pending tasks are complete, such as events or screen updates.

This does make a bit of sense as it sounds like it ensures that all list view animating etc is completed before making your call to ensure an item is visible.

<sub>See this thread for a related post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/2f11e46f-9421-4e31-93d3-fca06563ec41/</sub>

Comment: yeah i know that, now i put this portion of code in ready function and it should be worked fine with my ListView which is not the case, it doesn't generate any exception but i dont see any scrolling of changing of position of my scroll Bar . I want to know if ther is some specific html attributes. so this is my ListView:

Comment: @Brahim we may need to see more of you code then. I am using ensureVisible in several projects and it works fine as above so it has to be specific to something in your setup.

Comment: ensureVisible works for me as long as the app isn't in a snapped state.  Once it's snapped, ensureVisible no longer works.  Still looking for a solution.

Comment: @Beanwah Have you tried delaying the operating a little longer? Try something ridiculous like `setTimeout(function () { listView.ensureVisible(4); }, 3000);` and drop the timeout down from there.

Answer (score 0):

I might have an answer for you. You can't set the scroll position of a ListView immediately because the layout for the ListView has not been done yet and so attempting to scroll it to a position is futile. So you have to wait until the ListView gets to that state where its layout has been calculated. Here's how...

```
myListView.onloadingstatechanged = function () {
    if (app.sessionState.homeScrollPosition && myListView.loadingState == "viewPortLoaded") {
        myListView.scrollPosition = app.sessionState.homeScrollPosition;
        app.sessionState.homeScrollPosition = null;
    }
};
```

You can see this in context by looking at the /pages/home/home.js file in my open source [codeSHOW project](http://codeshow.codeplex.com).
Hope that helps.

Comment: yeh thinks a lot can u specify which part of code or which line ? that u use to auto scroll your listView in the right position of index.

Comment: Line 61 in /pages/home/home.js is where I set the scroll position (auto scroll to a position). On line 25 of the same file you can see where I am setting the scroll position. When the user navigates away from that page it saves the scroll position in a sessionState property.